# Python: How to construct a joyplot with values taken from a column in pandas dataframe as y axis

Tags: python, plotting

I have a dataframe df in which the column extracted_day consists of dates ranging between 2022-05-08 to 2022-05-12. I have another column named gas_price, which consists of the price of the gas. I want to construct a joyplot such that for each date, it shows the gas_price in the y axis and has minutes_elapsed_from_start_of_day in the x axis. We may also use ridgeplot or any other plot if this doesn't work.

[image]

This is the code that I have written, but it doesn't serve my purpose.

```
from joypy import joyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df['extracted_day'] = df['extracted_day'].astype(str)
joyplot(df, by = 'extracted_day', column = 'minutes_elapsed_from_start_of_day',figsize=(14,10))
plt.xlabel("Number of minutes elapsed throughout the day")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you're looking for, but does the plot you currently have not show what you want? In other words, what is still missing from your current plot?

Comment: @Oxbowerce The current plot basically plots the density (the number of readings that lie in the range given by the x axis). My requrement is that the y axis should consist of the gas_price and the x axis should consist of minutes_elapsed_from_the_start_of_the_day.